# How to create and export XML Reports in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, report, odoo-8

As default we can export our reports in Odoo as PDF or HTML. Also it seems possible to export to XLS, ODT etc. with help of some addons. But what I need is the XML format. Is it possible somehow in Odoo?

When I checked the Odoo implementation, I thought that maybe it was possible with a controller type report and some python code for controller to export as XML. So what are your insights about that?

Answer (score 0):

We have found that it is better to write custom code for this, either using lxml or for big outputs, xml.sax.saxutils.

Again, depending on the requirements and size of the file, we return it in a wizard or write to a disk location and email the user.

Comment: Hmm so, report type must be 'controller' for that?

Comment: Your addon is listed in Odoo Apps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download something in XML format, you should write a controller, and link it to a button. Take a look to my written file downloader here:

https://github.com/odoo-chile/l10n_cl_dte/blob/8.0/controllers/downloader.py

You can also check in the view, how I settled the button:

```
   <button string="Download XML" type="object" name="get_xml_file"
        class="oe_highlight" attrs="{
            'invisible':[('state', 'in', ['draft'])]}"/>
```

.. and the method defined in models/invoice.py:

```
def get_xml_file(self):
    return {
        'type' : 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': '/web/binary/download_document?model=account.invoice&field=sii_xml_request&id=%s&filename=demoxml.xml' % (self.id),
        'target': 'self',
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is this field=sii_xml_request? Is it from the model account.invoice?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that let you create a xml report: [**`report_xml`**](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/8.0/report_xml). You only need to add a dependency to your module and declare the report as a normal one like this:

```xml
<report
    id="example_xml_report"
    name="module_name.template_custom_id"
    string="Example XML Report"
    report_type="qweb-xml"
    menu="False"
    model="account.invoice" />
```

Then you can add the xml report with qweb. This is much more convenient that build it with the `lxml` library directly:

```xml
<template id="template_custom_id">
    <t t-call="report_xml.utf8_header">
        <FIRSTHEADER>
            <OPERATION t-esc="operation" />
            <OPERATIONTYPE t-esc="operation_type" />
            <VERSION t-raw="0">1.0</VERSION>    <!-- literal value -->

            <ELEMENT t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                <COMPANYNAME t-esc="o.company_id.name" />

                <!-- [...] -->
```

You can add a python class to process some custom data for the report as the rest of reports:

```py
class AccountInvoiceXmlReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = "report.module_name.template_custom_id"

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        """ If ``context`` contains a dict called ``docargs``, it will be used as
            the Qweb context. The special key ``docs`` will be added to ``docargs``
            automatically if missing.
        """

        # some operations

        docargs = self.env.context.get("docargs", dict())
        if "docs" not in docargs:
            docargs["docs"] = (account_invoice_obj)

        docargs.update({
            'operation': self.env.context.get('operation', False),
            'operation_type': self.env.context.get('operation_type', False)       # TODO >> verify the invoices have the same type
        })

        result = (
            self.env["report"].render(            # generate xml report
                self._name[len("report."):],
                docargs
            ).strip()
        )
        return result
```

As you can check in the `README.rst` the requirements:

- Install the `lxml` library.
- Install the repository `reporting-engine`

For further instructions about creating reports go [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html)